# wxPython: access sizer of GUI generated by wxFormBuilder and replace child

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxformbuilder, objectlistview-python

I want to buid my applications under the idea of an MVC, with sepparate GUI and controller. In addition, I have a workmate much better than me in graphical tasks, and we want to distribute the work: he build the graphical part with wxFormBuilder and I build the "machinery" of the application.

When I have the GUI generated, I want substitute some elements that wxFormbuilder cannot manage: by example, the wxObjectListView. My idea is create a GUI with a normal wxListBox, import it with the main program, and substitute it with an wxObjectListView. I don't want to modify directly the generated code by wxFormBuilder, because I want to maintain the backwards compatibility with the GUI editor.

The problem and the question are: from the main program that imports the GUI, how can I access the sizer that contains the list, delete and substitute by a ObjectListView? Something like sizer.Delete(list) and then sizer.Add(olv)...

Here you are an example:

The GUI code generated by wxFormBuilder: a Frame with a list and a button.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Sep  8 2010)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx

###########################################################################
## Class MyFrame1
###########################################################################

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 330,288 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        fgSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )
        fgSizer.AddGrowableCol( 0 )
        fgSizer.AddGrowableRow( 0 )
        fgSizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        fgSizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        m_listBox1Choices = [ u"Row1", u"Row2" ]
        self.m_listBox1 = wx.ListBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_listBox1Choices, 0 )
        fgSizer.Add( self.m_listBox1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        fgSizer.Add( self.m_button1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( fgSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

And here is the main code, that imports the graphical class.

```
from __future__ import print_function
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
from olvGUI import MyFrame1

class Ventana(MyFrame1):

    def inicia(self):
        hijos = self.GetChildren()
        for h in hijos:
            print(h)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    v = Ventana(None)
    v.inicia()
    v.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I attempt to access the Frame children, I only see the "final" objects, not the Sizer.

```
<wx._controls.ListBox; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxListBox *' at 0x1e0cea8> >
<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x19a5f90> >
```

Maybe the GUI must have another structure if I want make it his elements accesibles, but I have no idea how to make it. I have tried make two levels of sizers, and the final result is the same: I can access the final elements, not the sizers.

Comment: Yes! It works. I did:
`sizer = wx.Window.GetSizer(self)`
and 
`sizer = self.GetSizer()` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change `fgSizer` to `self.fgSizer` so you can access it later. Then you can use the sizer's `Remove` method to remove the widget. There is an `Insert` method that you can use to insert another widget in it's place.

See the documentation on sizers for full details:

- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html

Because you are removing and inserting a widget, you will most likely need to call `Layout` at the end of that method. This article has an example:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/05/wxpython-adding-and-removing-widgets-dynamically/

Finally, here's an example of getting the sizer:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Get sizer")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onGetSizer)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onGetSizer(self, event):
        """"""
        sizer = self.panel.GetSizer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is an example of saving your widget's index:

```
self.widget_dict = {}
some_boxsizer.Add(some_widget)  # this is the first widget, so its ID is zero
self.widget_dict[some_widget] = 0
```

Now in your event handler, you can use this dictionary to determine what widget is in which index:

```
index = self.widget_dict[some_widget]
```

Comment: I have it, thanks. I can now `Replace`, but this way the new widget doesn't inherit the proportion and flags of the replaced. `Prepend` or `Add` and later destroy the old widget works fine, in case it was the first or the last, and accept all the necessary parameters. I'll try `Insert` too, but the problem now is get the index of the old widget.

Comment: You could save the index of the widgets into a dictionary or list and use that to help you figure things out.

Comment: Mike: I don't have idea of how do it. This problem is making me realize that my knowledge of the wx structure tree and sizers, windows and widgets concepts (and who-contains-who) is weak.

Comment: I added a simple example to the end of my answer that might help you figure this out.